# Building a binary state chart in billboard.js for multiple pieces of equipment

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm attempting to make some charts for the first time using billboard.js and have come across a case that doesn't seem to be easily represented.  I want to display a binary (on/off) state of multiple items in one chart over a time period.  On and off periods are expected to be for a fair duration so I was hoping to display this using an x-axis of time and categories for the y-axis with a line present running left to right when the item is on and no line when it is off.

I've tried a few implementations using existing chart types in billboard.js and the closest I can seem to get is a scatter plot with overlapping points to create a 'line'.  This also requires that 'on' values be manipulated to allow display of more than one line on a chart (so they don't all overlap on the 1 value) Below code shows the setup for that and how data manipulation of the 'on' or 1 value would be required to show more than one item per chart.

```
bb.generate({
bindto: "#chart",
data: {
    columns: [
        ["item1", 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        ["item2", 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0]
    ],
    type: 'scatter',
    colors: {
      data1: "red",
      data2: "green"
    },
},
axis: {
  y: {
    min: 1,
    max: 2,
    tick: {
      values: [1,2],
    },
  },
},
point: {
  r: 10,
  focus: {
    expand: {
      enabled: false,
    }
  }
},
tooltip: {
  show: false,
},
```

});

(https://codepen.io/CodeRequiem/pen/rYeejz)

I'm considering just changing up to straight D3 but wanted to know if anyone had any suggestions for a better way to handle this within billboard.js.  An additional question is how to show the y-axis values as item1 and item2 instead of 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) On/off states represented in a line**

I don't know if this is what you want to diplay, but you can make as below setting changing size and y axis padding options.

[image]

- Working sample: https://codepen.io/netil/pen/JOXMZW

```js
bb.generate({
    bindto: "#chart",
    size: {
      height: 80
    },
    data: {
        columns: [
            ["item1", null, 1, 1, 1, 1, null, null, 1, 1, 1, 1, null, null, 1, 1, 1, 1, null, null, 1, 1, 1, 1, null, null, 1, 1, 1, 1, null, null, 1, 1, 1, 1, null, null, 1, 1, 1, 1, null, null, 1, 1, 1, 1, null, null, 1, 1, 1, 1, null, null, 1, 1, 1, 1, null, null, 1, 1, 1, 1, null, null, 1, 1, 1, 1, null, null, 1, 1, 1, 1, null, null, 1, 1, 1, 1, null],
            ["item2", 2, 2, 2, null, null, null, 2, 2, 2, null, null, null, 2, 2, 2, null, null, null, 2, 2, 2, null, null, null, 2, 2, 2, null, null, null, 2, 2, 2, null, null, null, 2, 2, 2, null, null, null, 2, 2, 2, null, null, null, 2, 2, 2, null, null, null, 2, 2, 2, null, null, null, 2, 2, 2, null, null, null, 2, 2, 2, null, null, null, 2, 2, 2, null, null, null, 2, 2, 2, null, null, null]
        ],
        type: 'scatter',
        colors: {
          data1: "red",
          data2: "green"
        },
    },
    axis: {
      y: {
        padding: {
          top: 180,
          bottom: 180
        },
        tick: {
          values: [1,2],
          format: function(x) {
            return "item"+ x;
          }
        },
      },
    },
    point: {
      r: 10
    },
    interaction: {
      enabled: false
    },
    clipPath: false
});
```

or you can directly manipulate data's element position using `onrendered` option
[image]

- https://codepen.io/netil/pen/NwNXjE

```js
    onrendered: function() {
      this.data.targets.forEach(function(v) {
        var id = v.id;
        var y = id === "item1" ? -120 : 100;
        
        d3.select(".bb-chart-line.bb-target-"+ id)
          .style("transform", "translateY("+ y +"px)");
      })
    }
```

**2) Changing y axis values**

You can use `axis.y.format` option for that.

https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/release/latest/doc/Options.html#.axis:y:format

```js
tick: {
  format: function(x) {
    return "item"+ x;
  }
},
```

Comment: This didn't answer my question directly, as my goal was to put multiple on/off states on the same 'chart' but on separate lines, without modifying the data from it's default 0 or 1 values.  It looks like I can use parts of your answer to solve my problem by using axis.y.format to alter tick values and by using onrendered to move the position of series elements as I was hoping to.  I will post another comment after making a pass at this.

Comment: This will work to achieve my goals as described in my last comment.  Marking as answer.

Comment: If you need more help, describing with image will be more clear to understand your needs. Anyway, hope the answer be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

As [Jae Sung Park](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4427557/jae-sung-park) mentioned, the solution includes using axis.y.tick.format to alter axis tick labels and using the onrendered function as shown below.

```
bb.generate({
axis: {
  y: {
    tick: {
      values: [1, 2],
      format: function(x) {
        if (x === 1) {
          return 'item1';
        }
        return 'item2';
      },
    },
  },
},
onrendered: function() {
  this.data.targets.forEach(function(v) {
    var id = v.id;
    var y = id === "heat" ? -25 : 0;

    d3.select(".bb-chart-line.bb-target-"+ id)
      .style("transform", "translateY("+ y +"px)");
  })
}
```

});

Full CodePen example here:
<strike>https://codepen.io/CodeRequiem/pen/rYeejz</strike> deleted pen

Answer (score 0):

In the time since using this answer, I've also discovered a better way to display the data... as a line chart.  Scatter plot looked odd and overlapping points produced different colors due to the default opacity of scatter plot points.

https://codepen.io/CodeRequiem/pen/rYeejz

```
CSS
.bb-line {
   stroke-width: 10px !important;
   stroke-linecap: round;
}

JS
var chart2 = bb.generate({
size: {
  height: 102,
},
bindto: "#chart2",
data: {
    columns: [
       ["heat2", ...same data],
       ["cool2", ...same data]
    ],
    type: 'line',
    colors: {
      'heat2': "orange",
      'cool2': "blue"
    },
},
axis: {
  y: {
    tick: {
      format: function(x) {
        if (x === 1) {
          return 'cool2';
        }
        return 'heat2';
      },
    },
  },
},
point: {
  r: 1
},
onrendered: function() {
  this.data.targets.forEach(function(v) {
    var id = v.id;
    var y = id === "heat2" ? -25 : 0;

    d3.select(".bb-chart-line.bb-target-"+ id)
      .style("transform", "translateY("+ y +"px)");
  })
}
```

});

As you can see in the above codepen, the same results are produced but with a line.  This avoids the issues I was having with scatter plot opacity of points and overlapping points looking very odd.  I updated the css to include **stroke-linecap: round** as well to round the edges of the stroke, making it properly presentable.